# OSX : QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery() is not returning latest values upon Proxy details change from System Preferences

Tags: c++, macos, qt, proxy

I am using the following code snippet to get the proxy details for the URL. First time it worked fine by giving the HTTPS proxy details configured in the System Preferences -> Network -> Proxies -> Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS).

If i change the IP value or credentials for HTTPS proxy then QT is not able to return the latest details. Even though i disabled the HTTPS proxy and then launch the app but still QT is giving old HTTPS proxy details.

The changes are getting reflected by QT only after i restart the machine. is this a known limitation or any work around?

QT version : 4.8.5

Mac OSx : 10.6 and 10.7

```
QNetworkProxyQuery npq(QUrl("https://www.google.co.in/"));

            foreach (QNetworkProxy proxy, QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery(npq)) {
                Log.info("HTTP", L"Proxy found for Auth: [%hs] Proxy Server: [%hs] Port: [%d] type:[%d]",
                      httpInfo[kUrl].toString().toStdString().c_str(),
                      proxy.hostName().toStdString().c_str(),
                      proxy.port(),
                      proxy.type());

            }
```

Comment: You should create a self-contained test case, and report it as a Qt bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not something related to QT. Found that even browsers also not picking up the latest values. Found an alternative like if we set proxy settings command line twice, all applications are picking up latest values.

**networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Ethernet 10.204.22.89 3128 On user1 test**